# Extract twitter tiny url from tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I am extracting url from tweets:

sample twitts are:

```
\'Whn I ws calld for ths song @VishalDadlani @5hekhar both said \"we finally hv the perfect song for u\" lulz http://t.co/6vzbyjfCGk #DramaQueen\' 


\'#FreeSunder @PMOIndia The world watches as India allows the torture of temple elephants to continue. PLEASE SHARE http://t.co/g8f1kgdasU\'
india
```

I want to get tinyurl from all such user tweets

my code:

```
<?php

$reg_exUrl = "/(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\/.]|[~])*)/";
// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "Whn I ws calld for ths song lulz http://t.co/6vzbyjfCGk #DramaQueen\ ";
// Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url))
    {
        echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='{$url[0]}'>{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);
    } else {       // if no urls in the text just return the text
       echo $text;
}
```

echo here prints actual tweets only

This gives only one url , how can I get all url from tweets?

Comment: @Sim0n222: it gives result `Whn I ws calld for ths song lulz http://t.co/6vzbyjfCGk #DramaQueen\ ` right? I want only url as a result

Comment: I updated my answer again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print just the URL:

```
echo "<a href='{$url[0]}'>{$url[0]}</a>";
```

If you want to match all URLs, use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

```
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $urls);
    foreach ($urls[0] as $url) {
        echo "<a href='{$url}'>{$url}</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo $text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this as you regex URL:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Check out the [source](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) for more info.